# Extra space between footnote numbers and content for high count

Tags: spacing, indentation, footnotes

I’m using the following commands to customize footnotes:

```
\usepackage[bottom,norule,hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{2mm}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{4mm}
\addtolength{\footskip}{2mm}
```

The results were as I wanted but only until the 10th footnote (see image below). Is there a way to define the the footnote text margin as a function of the horizontal space that the footnote number takes?

[image]

The numbers are flushed to the left and have the same margin as the main text. The footnote text margin, however, seems to be the main text margin plus a fixed quantity.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.  knowing what document class you use may be central to answering your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`footmisc` with the `hang` option has the property that if `\footnotemargin` is `0` or negative, then the hanging indent is set to the width of the footnote mark.  Thus:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[bottom,norule,hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\footnote{Long footnote text, to see whether we get
the hanging effect or not.  Just as a test.}\lipsum[4]
\footnote{Long footnote text, to see whether we get
the hanging effect or not.  Just as a test.}\lipsum[4]

\setcounter{footnote}{1010}
\footnote{Long footnote text, to see whether we get
the hanging effect or not.  Just as a test.}\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

produces the following reasonable effect with no overlapping

[image: No space sample]

What is lacking here is some spacing between the footnote mark and the text.  To correct this we can patch the relevant command in `footmisc` so that if the `hang` option is given and `\footnotemargin` is negative, we use the length information there to provide the spacing between the mark and the text, e.g. a value of `-0.5em` leads to a space of `0.5em`.  In the original package, if `\footnotemargin` is `<=0` then just the width of the footnotemark is used.  Below, we change one line so that the width of a box containing the footnotemark plus a skip of `-\footnotemargin` is used in the same situation:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[bottom,norule,hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{-0.5em}

\makeatletter
\ifFN@para
\else
  \long\def\@makefntext#1{%
    \ifFN@hangfoot
      \bgroup
      \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
        \ifdim\footnotemargin>0pt
          \hb@xt@\footnotemargin{\@makefnmark\hss}%
        \else
          \@makefnmark\hskip-\footnotemargin      %%Changed here
        \fi
      }%
      \leftmargin\wd\@tempboxa
      \rightmargin\z@
      \linewidth \columnwidth
      \advance \linewidth -\leftmargin
      \parshape \@ne \leftmargin \linewidth
      \footnotesize
      \@setpar{{\@@par}}%
      \leavevmode
      \llap{\box\@tempboxa}%
      \parskip\hangfootparskip\relax
      \parindent\hangfootparindent\relax
    \else
      \parindent1em
      \noindent
      \ifdim\footnotemargin>\z@
        \hb@xt@ \footnotemargin{\hss\@makefnmark}%
      \else
        \ifdim\footnotemargin=\z@
          \llap{\@makefnmark}%
        \else
          \llap{\hb@xt@ -\footnotemargin{\@makefnmark\hss}}%
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
    \footnotelayout#1%
    \ifFN@hangfoot
      \par\egroup
    \fi
  }
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\footnote{Long footnote text, to see whether we get
the hanging effect or not.  Just as a test.}\lipsum[4]
\footnote{Long footnote text, to see whether we get
the hanging effect or not.  Just as a test.}\lipsum[4]

\setcounter{footnote}{1010}
\footnote{Long footnote text, to see whether we get
the hanging effect or not.  Just as a test.}\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output with space]

Answer (score 6):

The only value that is important here, given the `hang` option, is:

```
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{2mm}
```

which is very small for any two digit number.  `footmisc` sets the length to `1.8em` by default, which might be too big for your taste unless your footnotes number in the 100s (in my experience, you really need at least `1.2em` if you get into the 100s).

Try this file, for example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[bottom,norule,hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{1.2em}
%\setlength{\footnotesep}{4mm}
%\addtolength{\footskip}{2mm} 

\begin{document}

\setcounter{footnote}{8}
\footnote{Test.}\lipsum[1]
\footnote{Test.}\lipsum[1]
\footnote{Test.}\lipsum[1]

\setcounter{footnote}{98}
\footnote{Test.}\lipsum[1]
\footnote{Test.}\lipsum[1]
\footnote{Test.}\lipsum[1]

\setcounter{footnote}{198}
\footnote{Test.}\lipsum[1]
\footnote{Test.}\lipsum[1]
\footnote{Test.}\lipsum[1]

\setcounter{footnote}{998}
\footnote{Test.}\lipsum[1]
\footnote{Test.}\lipsum[1]
\footnote{Test.}\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

As I know is the usual way to layout footnotes is to have a look to the resulting number of footnotes (for example 105) after you finished writing your text.

Now you can change `\setlength{\footnotemargin}{2mm}` to a value that gives you the wished space, for example `\setlength{\footnotemargin}{7mm}`.

So you get all footnotes layouted with the same space for the footnote number.

If you want to change the space after the 9th footnote you can use a second command `\setlength{\footnotemargin}{7mm}` as shown in the following MWE:

```
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79039/extra-space-between-footnote-numbers-and-content-for-high-count
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[bottom,norule,hang]{footmisc}

\setlength{\footnotemargin}{2mm}   % set space for first 9 footnotes

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum\footnote{footnote 1 now extends footnote now extends footnote now extends 
  footnote now extends footnote now extends footnote now extends
  footnote now extends} below the bottom margin 
which\footnote{This footnote 2 now extends} below the bottom margin 
which\footnote{This footnote 3 now extends} below the bottom margin 
which\footnote{This footnote 4 now extends} below the bottom margin 
which\footnote{This footnote 5 now extends} below the bottom margin 
which\footnote{This footnote 6 now extends} below the bottom margin 
which\footnote{This footnote 7 now extends} below the bottom margin 
which\footnote{This footnote 8 now extends} below the bottom margin 
which\footnote{This footnote 9 now extends} below the bottom margin 
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{7mm}  % set new space for number
which\footnote{This footnote 10 now extends footnote now extends 
  footnote now extends footnote now extends footnote now extends
  footnote now extends footnote now extends} below the bottom margin 
which\footnote{This footnote 11 now extends} below the bottom margin 
which\footnote{This footnote 12 now extends} below the bottom margin 
\end{document}
```

For me that looks not like a good typhography, so I personaly wouldn't do it.